# Functions not streaming audio when deployed to production

Tags: firebase, express, axios, google-cloud-functions, streaming

I have a firebase function that is designed to stream an audio as a response:

```js
import fetch from "axios";
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";

export const testAudioStream = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    const urlToFile = "https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-audio/t-rex-roar.mp3";
    const range = req.headers.range;

    // get media response
    const mediaResponse = range
        ? await fetch(urlToFile, { headers: { range }, responseType: "stream" })
        : await fetch(urlToFile, { responseType: "stream" });

    mediaResponse.data.pipe(res);
});
```

When I run this in **localhost** (using postman), it works great:

[image]

But when I deploy it to **production**, the response is different than when I tested it in localhost:

[image]

I believe this is due to the response headers. In **localhost**, the response headers returned are:

[image]

But in **production**, the response headers are different:

[image]

So my questions are:

1. Why are the results different depending on localhost and in production
2. How do I make the production function return the audio correctly?

**Edit:** The intent here is to hide the file URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solves this by just copying the headers to the response file:

```js
// copy headers
const newHeaders = Object.entries(mediaResponse.headers);
for (const [key, value] of newHeaders)
    res.setHeader(key, value);

// copy status code
res.status(mediaResponse.status);
```

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Functions does not support streaming. The entire request and response are sent in one chunk. You may want to read the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas#resource_limits) of its limitations.

If you want to return the audio, you have the option to return a html with `audio controls`. See code below:

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";

export const testAudioStream = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {

    res.send(`
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <body>

        <audio controls>

        <source src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-audio/t-rex-roar.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
        </audio>

        </body>
        </html>`
    )
});
```

Already tested on my end:
[image]

You could also return just the audio link and handle the link on the Front-end to properly play the returned audio.

Comment: Thanks. The intent behind streaming is to hide the audio URL from the user. In this case, firebase functions might not be an option for us.

Comment: I edited it. Though, if I can just send the audio URL anyways, I would have no need for a firebase function. I also mentioned my goal in the title of the post.